# Read / run a MATLAB script from a URL

Tags: matlab

Fairly simply question, but I cannot find an answer via Google or on Stack.

I have a use-case where it would be highly-preferable to simply read a `.m` MATLAB script from a URL.

How should I do this correctly?

Comment: Is [`urlread`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/urlread.html) what you want? That will give the contents as a string

Comment: I'm trying to essentially `include` other scripts in my script ... I'm thinking `run(urlread('http://myscript.m'))`?  Obviously that's not the real URL

Comment: The output of `urlread` is a string with the code. You would need to `eval` it, not `run`it. Or save the string to a text file and then run the file

Comment: From the linked docs, `urlread` is not recommended. Perhaps [`webread`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html) instead? Then `eval(webread('http://myscript.m'))` should work

Comment: Perfect -- `eval` is, I think, the answer to what I"m asking.  if you want, type that as an answer and I'll accept it for posterity.

Comment: Bear in mind that [`eval` is not recommended](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/) in general

Comment: Got it.  Actually, `eval(webread())` does not work due to `webread()` returning type uint8.  `eval(urlread())` does.

Needs to be `eval(char(webread(URL)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<disclaimer>
```

**Clearly only do this with files you have complete control of (and/or find a solution with better validation)**. This is a "dangerous" method as there is no check that you're not about to run a file which, for example, copies your entire harddrive to Bob's computer before corrupting it all. Bob and Alice might be spending the whole evening laughing at your embarrassing holiday photos.

Treat this more as a proof of concept than a how-to, it addresses your problem but by no means should be used in production code.

```
</disclaimer>
```

---

You'll need to use `eval` to evaluate code. Every time I mention `eval` I feel compelled to point out [it's not recommended](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/), in particular in this case because you could be evaluating whatever random code is living in that file on the web! In this case your only alternative is to save the file locally and call `run`.

Then you can use

```
eval(urlread('http://myscript.m'))
```

or, since `urlread` is not recommended (from the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/urlread.html)), you can use `webread` and specify that the output should be text [in the options](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html#inputarg_options)

```
eval(webread('http://myscript.m', weboptions('ContentType', 'text')))
```

Using `webread` appears to be *really* slow, not sure why when it's the recommended function. In light of this, `urlread` might be preferable.

---

There is a note in the `webread` docs which suggests you wouldn't even need to specify the `weboptions`

> If a web service returns a MATLAB® file with a .m extension, the function returns its content as a character vector.

Although you suggested that `webread` returned a uint8 variable which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to save a file from a URL then run it, you can use [`websave`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/websave.html) and [`str2func`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html) like so:

```
fcnName = 'newscript';    % Name for the function/script file
websave([fcnName '.m'], 'http://myscript.m');  % Download and save it
fcn = str2func(fcnName);  % Create function handle
fcn();                    % Evaluate function/script
```

It should of course go without saying that you want to be *really* sure you can trust the source of the file, otherwise you're gonna have a bad time.